# Looking up about 40k records out 150 million records in Cassandra in every job run?

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka

I am building a near real time/ microbatch data application with Cassandra as the lookup store. Each incremental run has ~40K records, while the Cassandra table has about 150 million records. In each run, I need to lookup the id field and get some attributes from Cassandra. These lookups can be random (not any time/ region/ country dependency), so there is no clear partitioning scheme.

How should I try to partition the Cassandra table to ensure decent/ good performance (for microbatches running every 15-30 mins)?

Apart from partitioning, any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

`joinWithCassandraTable` and `leftJoinWithCassandraTable` functions were specifically designed for efficient data lookup in Cassandra from Spark jobs. It performs fetching of data by primary or partition key, and because it's executed by multiple executors in parallel, it could be fast (although ~40K could still take time, but it depends on size of your Cassandra and Spark clusters). See the [SCC's documentation for detailed information](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12) how to use it - but remember, that these functions are available only in RDD API. The DataStax's version of connector has support for so-called "DirectJoin" - efficient joins with Cassandra in the DataFrame API.

Regarding partitioning - it depends on how do you perform lookup - you have 1 record in Cassandra matching one record in Spark? If yes, then just use this ID as primary key (it's equal to partition key in this case).